# letting kernel configure ipv6 on a tap interface

Tags: c, linux, ipv6

I have a situation where I create a tap interface on linux using C program. I can configure an ipv6 address on this interface as well using the ioctl command SIOCSIFADDR. and it gets set correctly.
But wat i want is to configure only Link-Local address (thats wat i set by above SIOCSIFADDR). and then Let the kernel do the global address allocation through SLAAC procedure. but I only succeed in setting the Link-local address. If I do a service network restart I can see the eth0 interface going UP and i can see the Router Solicitation requests too. but nothing for the interface that i bring up through programming. 
Is it possible to create an interface and let kernel manage its ipv6 interfaces itself.